# Swift expandable tableview

Tags: ios, swift

I am using an expandable tableview in swift. Suppose there are three rows in the tableview. Each row has on one view for their expandable. Now I expand the 2nd row, and reload either the full tableview or the particular 2nd row. In that case the expanded view get collapsed. But I want that the expanded cell doesn't get collapsed. So, is there any suggestion how can I stop collapsing the cell after reload?

Comment: please explain what you mean by collapsing.

Comment: Please check [this link](https://github.com/justinmfischer/SwiftyAccordionCells).I am using this library in my project.

Comment: Use an `var isExpanded: [IndexPath: Bool] = [:]` dictionary that sets whether the item is expanded. In the height `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` method give the right height according to the `Bool` value

Answer (score 1):

the best way would be to post an issue to the github repository, I believe the original developer can fix it.